# Trouble importing libraries from Processing into Eclipse

Tags: java, processing, libraries

I had a problem loading sound using the sound.processing library, so I am trying to use the ddf.minim library.

My Instructor imported the sound.processing library into processing AND Eclipse, and I don't remember how he did it. I tried going into processing and downloading minim from the sketch

When I try to import ddf.minim into my project, I get a red line under ddf. I also manually downloaded ddf.minim from github, removed the one previously installed, and I believe I had replaced it with the github files. I then went to add libraries in processing, and I still can't even import ddf.minim in Processing, let alone Eclipse!

Please help, I am just trying to get my sound to work in my Java project!

Comment: What do you mean by importing it into Processing **and** Eclipse? If you're using Eclipse, then you're using Processing as a Java library right? Why do you need to import anything into Processing if you're using Eclipse? By the way, the upper-case letters and the extra info about urgency are almost definitely going to attract downvotes, and possibly get your question closed.

Comment: Yes Processing is used as a Java library in Eclipse. I am importing it into eclipse because minim is a Processing library, and not a stand alone java one. Also, sorry, I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry, we aren't wizards here. We simply can't help on such input. You are like a guy calling his vet "my cat making strange noise. now different noise. now tell me what I should do".

Comment: We would at least need some real [mcve] here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Processing library and the Minim library to your classpath.

In Eclipse, to set your project’s classpath, right-click your project, and then click the Properties option. This brings up a dialog with all the settings you can specify for your project. Click the Java Build Path menu, and then the Libraries tab, which takes you to this screen:

[image: Eclipse build path screen]

This is your project’s classpath, and any library jars you want to use should be added here. Click the `Add External JARs...` button and select the `.jar` files that come with Processing. For basic sketches, I believe you only need the `core.jar` file.

Then for Minim, you can download the library `.zip` file from [here](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/). Unzip that wherever you want, and it should contain the `.jar` files that you need to add to your classpath.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) is a tutorial on using Processing as a Java library, and [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/eclipse) is a tutorial on using Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful response! Something weird is happening, though... Whenever I try to import ddf.minim.*, Eclipse has an auto fill box for ddf.minim, meaning that the library is probably imported properly, though the code automatically disappears whenever I import the library. This is the same for processing.sound

Comment: @ibloo I'm not sure what you mean by code disappearing. I wouldn't rely on Eclipse's autocomplete functionality too much, especially if you're just starting out. Can you try to get a simple example working? If you're still having trouble, please ask follow-up questions in their own post. Good luck!